# Binding a list of string to View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, this is so simple but I CAN"T GET IT DONE >:(

My ViewModel

```
public List<string> Answers = new List<string>();
```

My View

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Answers[0], new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    }
```

I get errors:

***Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index***

What the hell is wrong here?

EDIT:
Even if I try this, this won't bind and I don't get values in my Controller.

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Answers[@i]" value="" />
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Seems that answers is empty

Comment: @MongZhu Yes its empty. What I am trying to do here is that, it shows 4 textboxes. When I post the form, it then fills that list with each textbox's value. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: I've created a fiddle **[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1W22vZ)** and it seems to work as expected

Comment: Pass a collection passing 4 items to the view and use `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)` - but this is not the way to do it unless you always require all 4 textboxes to be filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the list first...something like:

```
public List<string> Answers = new List<string>();

foreach(var thing in Something){

Answers.Add(thing);

}
```

Comment: I replaced your Answers[0] with Answers[i]

Comment: Okay, I see i you put 'i' there but not the situation is same, I get "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." error.

Comment: How are you populating the list 'Answers'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@model ModelName` at the top of your view. Without this, it will not know what it is you are trying to loop through. Make answers a property in your model add `@model ModelWithAnswers` at the top of your view and iterate the property.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the Index out of range is occurring because you are referencing an element in the collection that does not exist.

Resolve that issue, make sure your iterator is constrained by the elements, for example:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Answers[i], new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}
```

If there are no answers in your model, you will get no text boxes. From your description I assume you want at least 4, so make sure you populate your Model with empty strings or nulls when you construct it.